# paperspace dask.distributed Worker failed to start

Tags: python-3.x, dask-distributed

I am trying to use dask.distributed on a gradient machine at paperspace, but the following doesn't work on neither CPU and GPU machine.

```
from dask.distributed import Client 
client = Client()

TimeoutError: Worker failed to start
```

Any thoughts of how to "fix" it?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: It works for me locally. And still, no clue why it isn't working on paperspace.